# Bit And Operation in Decimal Column in Impala

Tags: hive, impala

Consider in impala, I have a decimal column, is there a way to convert to binary using bin function

I can see clearly that [bin](https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_math_functions.html#math_functions__bin) is accepting only big int argument not the decimal

So, if there is a number like 122642280288770432172031 which is crossing the big int limit in impala, how do I convert it to binary form and use a bit and(https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_bit_functions.html#bit_functions__bitand) operation on it?

Also, let us know if there is a possibility in Hive if not for impala

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in udf to achieve this. In hive [conv](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-MathematicalFunctions) udf is available however if you pass a number that exceeds the max bigint value, it will return its max binary representation(`1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`). I think the only way that you have to achieve this is creating your own udf to handle the conversion. Probably the same will apply for the `bitand` udf of input values exceed the number limit.